# Which color is pink?

Tags: color

This question concerns the plain color name *pink* only (rather than its variations, such as *Light Pink*, or the subjective perceptions of various people, or ink names (such as *Pink C*), or the pink color *range*, all of which exist in it own right) for technical purposes.

We've recently noticed that the plain English color name *pink* has been assigned to two different RGB values for a very long time; cf. https://github.com/latex3/xcolor/issues/24 , https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/rgb/-/issues/1 .  Outside the applications mentioned there (xcolor, Groff, X11, Wikipedia, HTML, and CSS), what SHOULD *pink* be? E.g., what is the definition of the *pink* color according to the various longstanding standards ANSI, ISO, DIN, ГОСТ, RAL, and NCS?

Comment: @user287001 It's *rose* or *incarnat* from Pas-de-Calais inwards, IMHO. I don't care which color it is exactly but rather that the folks agree on terminology for pragmatic purposes.

Answer (score 8):

This can't be answered.

"Pink" is not a scientific or math formula. It's a subjective name chosen by a viewer. 500 viewers may all choose a [*different* color](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pink%20color&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1876&bih=1227&ei=srEbY9qDFKiy0PEP1LSCsAU&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYxu_wnoYoReEXVl2oHy5EQDkym9VtStM&ved=0ahUKEwjapL2h1Yj6AhUoGTQIHVSaAFYQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=Pink%20color&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIICAAQgAQQsQMyCAgAEIAEELEDMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATILCAAQgAQQsQMQgwEyBQgAEIAEMgsIABCABBCxAxCDATIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CAgAELEDEIMBUABY9ApgrgxoAHAAeACAAUWIAd0EkgECMTCYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img) to designate as "pink".

While most viewers may agree that "pink" is a lighter shade of a red hue — pink, ultimately, is whatever you say it is.

Comment: Not when you have at least two folks to agree precisely on what they mean when writing *pink* and meaning a single color. E.g., often in computer code concerning colors, in documentation, or in specification. We stumbled upon the issue when preparing for a talk. That's what standards are made for, after all …

Comment: Color names are merely what's been designated by *that* system. There's no "universal" understanding of any color by *name*. This is *exactly* why color matching systems exist. If everyone uses the *same* color matching system, then everyone can assume the name in use will be the same color seen by everyone else using that same system. So if you want to use "pink" as a designation one should *also* specify the *system* which is in use... i.e. Pink as designated by ANSI. - Pantone "pink" will most likely NOT match TOYO "pink", etc.

Comment: Only if there are two established color systems in which *Pink* are, well, really different colors. As a counterexample, presumably black and white are the same in all systems that provide the plain name *Black* – you don't need to specify the color system.

Comment: Anyway, if Pantone and TOYO (never heard of it) provide the plain name *pink*, please feel free to mention their definitions. Concerning your link: the search also yields named variations of pink (which do exist in their own right), e.g., *Light Pink*. Our question, on the contrary, concerns plain pink.

Comment: Black is *not* the same in all systems. [Toyo Pink](https://www.toyo-chem.com/en/products/natural/liofleshcolor/powder_for_tableting.html), [Pantone Pink](https://www.pantone.com/connect/PINK-C) -- My **point** is it's exceptionally difficult, if not impossible, to find 2 systems which will designate the same color by "name". "Names" *aren't* formulas.

Comment: You provided *Pink **C*** of Pantone (they typeset it as rgb(214, 37, 152) internally, I think). Does Pantone have no plain *Pink*? I have no interest whatsoever in *Pink C* or any other identifiers consisting of *pink* with prefixes, suffixes, or modifiers, and no interest in compound words with *pink*. As for *pink* in the Toyo system (they typeset it as #fa1fa3 for the Web), thx!

Comment: The `C` merely means coated stock.

Comment: Oh; I didn't know that. So, *C* refers more to the material rather than to the reflected-light spectrum, right?

Comment: Yes. C is coated stock, U is uncoated stock.. it's showing the color as it will appear based upon the substrate - but the formula for the color remains the same.

Comment: Gotcha. Interestingly, the RGB values used on their Web page differ substantially: `(214, 37, 152)` for [Pink C](https://www.pantone.com/connect/PINK-C) and `(209, 66, 141)` for [Pink U](https://www.pantone.com/connect/PINK-U).

Comment: It would be more correct to call Pantone Pink an *ink* rather than a *color*. It's a physical product that comes in a can. When you apply it to different kinds of paper, you get different resulting colors. That's what the coated and uncoated color books show for two specific kinds of paper. Pantone merely provides consistent inks, not consistent colors.

Comment: To the down voter If I'm wrong, then please answer with a correct formula. Thanks.

Comment: @Wolff Do you think this could be the reason for the difference in the RGB values on their Web pages for *Pink C* and *Pink U*?

Comment: @GeekestGeek yes that is the reason.

Comment: @GeekestGeek reason for different RGB values? RGB is not Pantone. RGB values are an attempt to simulate using light-emitting diodes the Pantone color which, as stated by others, are physical inks. Uncoated stock reflects light differently, this causes a visible difference which is then *simulated* using RGB. The light source used when digitizing/sampling the physical ink mix will also affect the RGB values.

Comment: But, as Scott intimated you are asking a cultural question, and there is no one pink. So quoting the system and or a value is the right way, saying "pink" is handy as a sanity check in case the RGB is quoted wrong, but should not be relied on for color fidelity. Side note: I have seen pinks named "cotton candy," but most cotton candy I have ever seen in real life was blue

Answer (score 2):

**Lots of different colors are called pink**

Color names are all over the place. We simply can not agree on a name for all colors. Dont believe us? Well its handy then that [XKCD](https://blog.xkcd.com/2010/05/03/color-survey-results/) made a color survey. Theres even the raw data for you to play with. It is clear that a huge number of different colors are categorized as pink.

[image]

**Image 1**: A image showing the range of names people use. image by XKCD

So no there is no way you can make people agree what the canonical pink color is as the color variation is pretty big. Some of which I personally wouldn't agree being pink. Color names aren't really all universal. Good thing is you can call nearly anything in a huge range anything you like pink.

Comment: While for the purposes casual communication I might (or might not) agree with you, this is irrelevant. First, for technical purposes (and graphic design is mostly technical) you *should* agree on what pink is, simply to ensure that you and your interlocutor or reader mean exactly the same. Second, what XKCD really means are ranges, not singular colors. Our question above is NOT about ranges.

Comment: @GeekestGeek it is your asking what color is called pink answer is a range of color is called pink no singular color is epitome of pink. So its perfectly reasonable to have 2 different colors called pink. And no there is no technical committee out there who has final say so on what is pink. Essential this not how humanities work its okay to have a holistic view where there lots of things called pink. If you must hit some target its your job to get client to define pink for you. So in essence **there is no clear meaning what a color name means** not in graphic design or anywhere else.

Comment: Except maybe red.

Comment: @joojaa First, you personally think of pink as of a range (and in casual environments, I might probably agree). The applications mentioned in the OP, however, think of *pink* as a single color.  You might not like this (and if so, you could consider making a case for dropping the single-color name *pink* on the technical level). Second, concerning humanities, you might call me way too sober today, but to me, the concept of color is much more on the technical side than on the humanities side.

Comment: @GeekestGeek perhaps. But the thing is human visual system is not altogether too specific so the tolerance for what is same name color is very big. Simply human eyes are way too unspecific for a definitive understanding of something. How would it be useful to have a rigid definition of pink if people wouldn't agree with you. Second color technically is complicated, since eyes don't measure the surrounding environment well. So in  the casual term color is undefined, do you mean paint, monitor instructions, psychological sensation, a wavelength, a specific combination of wavelengths etc.

Comment: You are inserting already very unspecific things. Even you aren't really definitive what color is #FF4400? Its not technically defined until you tell what calibration/profile your monitor has. In fact its entirely possible that FF does not even describe the red channel (yes profiles allow this)

Comment: @joojaa Humans are not specific about a range of perceptions. For example, you, given only your senses, are seldom able to tell whether whether the air around you has "normal temperature and pressure", at least roughly. Still, there is a worldwide standard for this: 20 °C and 1 bar. The imprecision of us humans is not an excuse for disagreeing on the meaning of things. The same for 0 degrees: you as a human don't really feel this with your senses.

Comment: As for #FF4400, it's not a proper name, such as *pink* or *red*, so I don't think this is relevant. You may make an argument that we should agree on what #FF4400 is, but it would be a different argument than on agreeing on what *pink* is, because, as you rightfully say, there should be a reference system. For *pink*, the reference system could be RGB or CIE-lab. For #FF4400, the reference system should be something else, clearly. Summarized, the question on what #ff4400 actually means is good, but it's still a different question. Let's not mix thing up.

Comment: @GeekestGeek good luck with getting a better answer. Ting is even the technical world is full of unspecific things.

Comment: @GeekestGeek "pink" and "red" are **not** "proper names" -- the entire point is that **no "name"** is *ever* "proper". The very nature of color *names* is that they are **always** subjective.

Comment: @Scott And the *hot* temperature is also subjective until you say this to a plumber and he gives you the exact threshold above which the tubes to your heating radiator count as technically *hot*.

Comment: @GeekestGeek havent you noticed that the colors we call cool are in fact warmer than the colors we call warm if you heat a piece of metal hot glowing red is in fact less warm than glowing blue. So no technical discussion of color does not match reality.

Comment: @joojaa *Cool/warm colors* is using the terms *cool* and *warm* in figurative sense. We do not go that far. If you stay with the main meaning of words, technical discussion of colors is very well possible.

Comment: @GeekestGeek yes thats the point your ready to accept that things aren't always defined but then you insist that pink must be defined. Thing is language is not a perfect technical instrument and normal language puts too much onus on us here. Pink is not a technical term

Comment: @joojaa The imperfection or, better put, vagueness of plain-English terms is not an excuse. Take “standard conditions” as an example.

Comment: @GeekestGeek sure. But if such a definition exists then i nor anybody that counts has ever heard of it. Which makes it a pretty useless definition. Also i wouldn't agree to follow it.

Comment: Also problem is it needs to work in other languages too.

Comment: @joojaa Lot of folks said *I wouldn't agree to follow it* and continued to stick to their beloved Réaumur thermometer. In contradiction to you, they have at least the advantage to know what they are talking about and communicate with folks using the same scale.

Answer (score 1):

Approaching your question directly, "**PINK COLOR**" is not a color reference and could mean anything in our own color perception. Naming "**PINK**" certain values and accept them as "**PINK**" would be something directly for our own use or as a reference in our working place but not somenthing we should use as a standard to refer to an specific color.

We define color as the visible spectrum the human eye is capable to perceive from the whole electromagnetic radiation spectrum; the human visible spectrum ranges from 380 to 740 nanometers and stands in between ultraviolet and infrared, the visible spectrum starts with violet and ends up on what is called deep red. "**Pink**" has certainly started some debates because it seems to be missing on the visible spectrum but at the end is there for our eyes to see and our brain to process it.

"**Pink**" is only a rough description of a color that is also called fuchsia or magenta. When we hear the word "**Pink**" our brain will give us a reference of the color that we, perhaps unconsciously, have previously defined as the "**Pink Color**” for ourselves and that perception is impossible to be explained to others without the use of a reference. We may be able to orient others about the "Pink" we have in mind by adding additional reference such as "*Light* **Pink**", "*Dark* **Pink**" or "*Fluorescent* **Pink**" (as it is mentioned in your question) but without showing a practical reference we will still have huge differences between the "Pink" we have in mind and the one other may have thought. This is the reason as mentioned by [Scott](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3270/scott) in his answer that colors are referenced as **Subjective**.

The only way to properly define to others the "Pink" we have in mind is by using a reference which could be for example a printed or painted example, a reference from a color library such as *Pantone* or *Toyo* or by giving them the values of the specific color we wish. For printed products my first chose would be to use a reference chart (printed) to rapidly define a specific color with anybody because we know that the selected option can be reproduced accurately either by using a spot ink or by reproducing it through CMYK with the given values. This could also apply to electronic references my by others and stablished as “**Pink**”.

Also, it is important to consider that the in the past years several digital presses manufacturers are offering a spot "**Pink**" ink or toner which is causing influence on people to move their own "**Pink**" perception to the one these manufacturers are offering. This is practically the same situation happening with **CSS Pink (HEX #FFC0CB)**, it was stablished, and it is a reference.

For general purposes I would suggest that the best way to define a color precisely is by using **CIELab Values**, even though, not all "**Pink**" options can be printed using CMYK, software will provide you the proper aids to pick the closets CMYK printable option as well as a direct reference to the closets option of "**Pink**" on a color reference chart, it's HEX reference as well as the RGB values for it.

Comment: Concerning your first para, then you get a mess when two working groups, each with their own view of whatever term you wish (here: the pink color), start collaborating. Pragmatically, a difference in the meaning causes a loss of time at least. Your “should not” is an exaggeration. E.g., for a long time, the world has been employing different views on which scale to use for speaking about temperature (e.g., what is 0 degrees), until lord Kelvin came by. Today, we have the *absolute zero* and the *normal temperature* worldwide. Clearly, a gain!

Comment: So I see no reason for why particular color names should be treated any differently than particular temperature degrees or temperature names.

Comment: Concerning your “missing on the visible spectrum”: what do you mean by that? Concerning values in CIE-Lab: any suggestion?